# Calculate mean euclidean distances between items within groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to calculate the mean euclidean distances between each item and all other items in a group within a data frame. I'd like to do this within the tidyverse, but can't seem to get it to work how I want.

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(Item = letters[1:20], Grp = rep(1:4, each = 5), 
                  x = runif(20, -0.5, 0.5), 
                  y = runif(20, -0.5, 0.5))
```

I think euclidean distances are calculated using:

```
sqrt(((x[i] - x[i + 1]) ^ 2) + ((y[i] - y[i + 1]) ^ 2))
```

I've tried, without success, to do something with `mutate`.

```
DF %>%
  group_by(Grp, Item) %>%
  mutate(Dist = mean(sqrt(((x - lag(x, default = x[1])) ^ 2) + 
                           (y - lag(y, default = y[1])) ^ 2)))
```

But, it doesn't work and only returns NA's.

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   Grp, Item [20]
   Item    Grp       x       y  Dist
   <fct> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a         1 -0.212   0.390     NA
 2 b         1  0.288   0.193     NA
 3 c         1 -0.0910  0.141     NA
 4 d         1  0.383   0.494     NA
 5 e         1  0.440   0.156     NA
 6 f         2 -0.454   0.209     NA
 7 g         2  0.0281  0.0441    NA
 8 h         2  0.392   0.0941    NA
 9 i         2  0.0514 -0.211     NA
10 j         2 -0.0434 -0.353     NA
11 k         3  0.457   0.463     NA
12 l         3 -0.0467  0.402     NA
13 m         3  0.178   0.191     NA
14 n         3  0.0726  0.295     NA
15 o         3 -0.397  -0.475     NA
16 p         4  0.400  -0.0222    NA
17 q         4 -0.254   0.258     NA
18 r         4 -0.458  -0.284     NA
19 s         4 -0.172  -0.182     NA
20 t         4  0.455  -0.268     NA
```

If I understand `lag` correctly it would still be sequential (if it worked), rather than computing distances between all pairs within a group.

How can I get the mean of all 4 distances for each item in a group?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `?dist` is a good place to start.

Comment: I don't think `dist` will accomplish what I need, since it requires a numeric matrix or dataframe and I'm trying to calculate specific pairwise (row-wise) distances.

Comment: Thanks! Your example below is awesome!

Comment: When a function does more-or-less what you want (calculate pairwise distances) but requires input in a slightly different form (matrix instead of data frame), it's usually easier to transform what you have into the required form than write your own function scratch.

Answer (score 4):

```
DF %>% group_by(Grp) %>%
    mutate(Dist = colMeans(as.matrix(dist(cbind(x, y)))))
# # A tibble: 20 x 5
# # Groups:   Grp [4]
#      Item   Grp            x            y      Dist
#    <fctr> <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1      a     1 -0.197904299  0.363086055 0.4659160
#  2      b     1  0.090540444 -0.006314185 0.2031230
#  3      c     1  0.101018893 -0.025062949 0.2011672
#  4      d     1  0.006358616 -0.149784267 0.2323359
#  5      e     1  0.219596250 -0.341440596 0.3605274
#  6      f     2 -0.493124602 -0.002935820 0.5155365
# ...
```

To see how it works, start with one data subset and go piece by piece:

```
# run these one line at a time and have a look at ?dist
dd = DF[DF$Grp == "1", c("x", "y")]
dist(dd)
as.matrix(dist(dd))
colMeans(as.matrix(dist(dd)))
```